# Auto-build stuck on Android studio after update

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, configuration

I updated my Android studio to the latest version 2020.3.1, including Android Gradle Plugin v7.0.2 and Gradle v7.2.
After some configuration nightmare (as always with AS, no surprises there), I managed to make my project compile and run, everything seemed smooth. But I realized not long after that the "auto-build" feature is actually stuck.
Basically my AS is not auto building while I am coding, meaning that I cannot even see basic error like typos and such until I actually build my project with CTRL+B.

I can see that I have an error in the auto-build section telling me:
Error:java: warning: source release 11 requires target release 11

I tried pretty much all JDK possible with different config, from 1.8 to 17. All of them trigger that error...

Here is how it looks like:
[image]

I am getting desperate at that point, I'll take any suggestion in order to fix that issue.

Comment: Did you try invalidate caches/restart?

Comment: I already tried the invalidate cache & restart several time, I even re imported the project from github, no luck.

Comment: have faced same issue  and none of the solution worked, event if build succeeds AS won;t show design view , i just installed bumbleBee from caranay channel and loving it. ..give it a try,

Comment: At this point deleting fully AS and reinstalling is my only option, so I might try to give the latest Canary version a try... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nothing helped, so I deleted fully my Android Studio and reinstalled the latest Canary version, which solved the issue.
I honestly think this is the best/fastest course of action for this kind of problem, unfortunately...

Comment: you can actually use both versions same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- try modifying the `target bytecode` & `project bytecode` in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler` -> set `target bytecode` & `project bytecode` version to `11`.
- check in `File | Project Structure | Modules` that all of your modules are registered as `java 11`
- check in `File | Project Structure | Modules` for each module, in the `Dependencies` tab, `Module SDK` is registered as `java 11`
- check in `File | Project Structure | Platform settings | SDKs` that only one `JDK` is present (to avoid potential conflict)
- check in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle` that `Gradle JVM` is `Java 11`
- delete your `Android Studio` and everything related to it (setting, cache, profile) on your computer and reinstall it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I tried/checked all points and everything seems correct already.

Comment: If it's still not working, go to `File | Invalidate caches` and check `clear file system` & `clear downloaded shared index`.

Comment: I already tried the invalidate cache & restart several time, I even re imported the project from github, no luck.
I cannot find the clear file system & clear downloaded shared index though, where is it?

Comment: I have it once I clicked `Invalidate caches` as shown here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html but maybe it's a bit different in `AS`. Did you check your `Gradle` configuration file, is it in `Java 11`? When you build your project with `Project | Build project`, does it work? if so, maybe it's a bug in AS.

Comment: Yes, I did check several time the Gradle config file and couldn't find anything weird about it.
I can indeed build my project, no issue whatsoever.

Comment: Hmmm that's not good, there must be a conflict somewhere with the auto-build functionnality. I've hadded two last point in my answer you might want to check.